# Some css properties don't work

Tags: html, css

I want to place noscript tag like on this (stackoverflow) page:

```
<noscript>Your browser has JavaScript turned off !</noscript>
```

But, commented properties doesn't work:

```css
noscript{
    width:100%; // I want it to be 100% of parent container width - it's not.
    text-align:center;
    background-color:crimson;
    color:white;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin-top:10px; // doesn't work
    padding-top:7px;
    margin-bottom:10px; // doesn't work
    padding-bottom:7px;
}
```

Comment: Please mention the browser with version too.

Comment: it doesnt work because you dont have display:block;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `display:block` in your css to make it a block element, `<noscript>` is not a block element.

Answer (score 7):

noscript is not a block element. Put a DIV or any other block element inside your noscript element and then attempt to style it.

Answer (score 1):

The content inside the `<noscript>` element will only be displayed if scripts are not supported, or are disabled in the user's browser. And it is not a block element.

Add `display:block` to your CSS.